# How can I use Callout to label the segments of a piecewise function?

Tags: plotting, labeling, piecewise

When I plot a `Piecewise` function, I like to put the function name above each part of the plot. I could not find a way to use `Callout`. So now I use `Text` to manually put the function name above each part of the curve. Here is MWE

```
ClearAll[x,h];
h[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[x],x < -1}, {1 - x^2, -1 < x < 1}, {Sin[Pi x], x > 1}}];
Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Obviously, putting the `Callout` inside `Piecewise` does not work.

```
h[x_] := 
  Piecewise[
    {{Callout[Exp[x], "Exp[x]"], x < -1}, 
     {1 - x^2, -1 < x < 1}, 
     {Sin[Pi x], x > 1}}];
```

So now I do the following, which requires few trials and errors to get the labels in the right place.

```
h[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin[Pi x],x > 1}, {1 - x^2, -1 < x < 1}, {Exp[x], x < -1}}];
Plot[h[x], {x, -3, 3},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.2, 1.2}},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  BaseStyle -> 12,
  Epilog -> 
    {Text["Exp[x]", {-2, .3}], 
     Text["1-x^2", {.4, 1.1}],
     Text["Sin[Pi x]", {1.7, .3}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My question is: Is there a trick to use `Callout` when plotting `Piecewise` function?

V 12 on windows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

h[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[x], 
     x < -1}, {1 - x^2, -1 < x < 1}, {Sin[Pi x], x > 1}}];

plotRng = {-3, 3};
```

**EDIT:** Extracting intervals

```
intervals = {Cases[h[x][[1, All, -1]], _?NumericQ, 2], plotRng} // 
    Flatten // Union // Partition[#, 2, 1] &;

Show[
 Plot[
    Callout[h[x], 
     Simplify[h[x], Less @@ Insert[#, x, 2]] //
       TraditionalForm // ToString,
     Above,
     Appearance -> None,
     Background -> None],
    {x, Sequence @@ #},
    PlotStyle -> Red] & /@
  intervals,
 PlotRange -> {plotRng, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You can find the endpoints automatically like this: `endpoints = Cases[
   pl,
   Line[coords_] :> ({First@#, Last@#} &@Sort[First /@ coords]),
   Infinity];` where `pl` is the original plot.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT**

The code below doesn't work anymore - see the comments

**END OF THE EDIT**

It is possible to nest several `Callout`:

```
   ClearAll[x, h];
    h[x_] := Piecewise[{{Exp[x], 
         x < -1}, {1 - x^2, -1 < x < 1}, {Sin[Pi x], x > 1}}];
    Plot[
     Callout[Callout[Callout[h[x], "Exp[x]", -2], "Sin[Pi x]", 2], 
      "1-x^2", {0.3, Above}], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Seen in [this video](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=2482) of Wolfram Technology Conference 2018.
There is a notebook attached to this video - see Section "parametric Curve Labeling"

Comment: It seems that the nested Callout does not work with Mathematica 12.1.

Comment: confirming, for Linux

Comment: I have just tested the code above with 12.1 on Windows 7. I confirm It doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[pwToCE]
pwToCE[f_] := ConditionalExpression @@@ f[#][[1]] &

positions = {-2, {.5, Above}, {1.5, Below}};

Plot[Evaluate@MapThread[Callout[#, #[[1]], #2] &, {pwToCE[h][x], positions}],
   {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1]]
```

[image]